# Why are my svn ant tasks failing?

Tags: apache-flex, svn, ant, svnant

I am trying to run a build script and I keep getting errors during a specific svn task. When I  try to build the target from the command line, I get an authentication error. When I run the build from flex builder I get an error saying "please get a newer Subversion client". From what I can tell there is a root issue that can be seen here when doing an ant -verbose:

```
svn_update:
    [echo] Updating the project source...
     [svn] Using javahl
     [svn] <Update> started ...
     [svn] update /Users/dave/Documents/Flex Builder 3/AssetLibrary -r HEAD --force
     [svn] At revision 373.
     [svn] <Update> finished.
     [ant] Exiting /Users/dave/Documents/Flex Builder 3/Simulation/build-template/commonbuild.xml.
     [ant] Exiting /Users/dave/Documents/Flex Builder 3/AssetLibrary/build.xml.
    [echo] Updating DataService Source

...

svn_update:
    [echo] Updating the project source...
     [svn] Using command line
     [svn] <Update> started ...
     [svn] up -r HEAD /Users/dave/Documents/Flex Builder 3/DataService --non-interactive
     [svn] svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.example.com/{redacted}': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: ignored NTLM challenge, rejected Basic challenge (https://svn.example.com)
     [svn] <Update> failed !
     [ant] Exiting /Users/dave/Documents/Flex Builder 3/Simulation/build-template/commonbuild.xml.
     [ant] Exiting /Users/dave/Documents/Flex Builder 3/DataService/build.xml.
     [ant] Exiting /Users/dave/Documents/Flex Builder 3/Simulation/build.xml.
```

As you can see, the second (failing) svn_update target is using command line, and the first (working) update is using javahl. I am using the default attributes for svn, so javahl should default to be used.

I updated my svnant jars to 1.3.0.

Would love some help with this one!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

First thing that's catching my eye is that the javahl one isn't calling the update on the same directory as the last one:

/Users/david.marr/Documents/Flex Builder 3/AssetLibrary

vs.

/Users/david.marr/Documents/Flex Builder 3/DataService

It could be that there is some other SVN problem underlying and you're just getting a misleading error message. Also, are you sure url https://svn.frogdesign.com/{redacted} is being parsed correct whatnot? "{redacted}" doesn't look like ANT syntax to me, and neither a regular url.

Comment: Thanks tehmou,
I removed the url from the paste and added {redacted}. I just wasn't sure it was cool to paste my company's svn repo structure. 

I agree though, the difference is the javahl call. I don't thing there is anything in the build script that would cause that though.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it seems I was restating the obvious then. I just happen to have these issues sometimes when unparsed things are left in the requests :P

With what kind of command do you run the first one? I am only familiar with running ANT scripts from Eclipse or command-line, and it sounds like this working one is executed from somewhere else?

Comment: They are both run via a svn_update task. No extra parameters are used to tell one to use command line and one to use javahl. Is this a known issue at all?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your command line client is too old, and the server has a versioning constraint on clients allowed to connect? What does `svn --version` say?

Comment: svn, version 1.6.6 (r40053)
   compiled Oct 22 2009, 14:13:09

Comment: Well, I don't really care which version you use, but the **server** might. You'll want to talk to the server admins about that.

Comment: "Rejected Basic challenge" sounds suspiciously like a server attempting to verify that the connected client is new enough.

Comment: Hmm,
I am running the opencollab svn binaries. Seems like they would be new enough. It's odd because other svn_update tasks are working correctly.   Additionally this repo is the same server as the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

I usually get the `Could not authenticate to server: ignored NTLM challenge, rejected Basic challenge` error I use svn update in non interactive mode (example: `svn update --non-interactive > output.txt`) and when my NT or Active Directory password has changed. The way to fix this would be to first run `svn update > output.txt` which will then prompt you for your password. Once provided, you will get the following

```
Authentication realm: <http://svnserver:80> SVN Server
Password for 'siacca':
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ATTENTION!  Your password for authentication realm:

   <http://svnserver:80> SVN Server

can only be stored to disk unencrypted!  You are advised to configure
your system so that Subversion can store passwords encrypted, if
possible.  See the documentation for details.

You can avoid future appearances of this warning by setting the value
of the 'store-plaintext-passwords' option to either 'yes' or 'no' in
'/cygdrive/u/.subversion/servers'.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Store password unencrypted (yes/no)? yes
```

Once this is done (I'm with you, I don't like storing my password unencrypted either, but this is the only way I can run automated nightly svn updates), you should be able to run svn update in non-interactive mode.